# Find total number of frequently occurrence elements

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, public-key-pinning

I was recently working on group of numbers, 
i have a large sequence of numbers stored vertically.
i was counting which number how many times appears, and then i chose the number(s) with high hit counts.

my code looks like this:

```
 // select the most repeated number 
 int countArray[1000];
    seq_len = i;
    for (i=0; i < seq_len; i++) {
            scanf("%d", page_seq[i]);
            countArray[i] = -1; 
 }

    for(i=0; i < seq_len; i++) {
            count = 1;
            for( j = i+1; j < seq_len; j++) {
                    if(page_seq[i] == page_seq[j]) {
                            countArray[j] = 0;
                            count++;
                    }
            }
            if(countArray[i] != 0) {
                    countArray[i] = count;
            }
    }
     //print count of each page frequency
    for(i=0; i < seq_len; i++) {
            if(countArray[i] != 0) {
            printf("page %d : count %d\n", page_seq[i], countArray[i]);
            }
    }

      //distinguish most frequently readed page and print its read count

     int most_freq;
 int maxPage=-1, maxPageIdx=-1;
 int pinned_page;
    for(i=0; i < seq_len; i++) {
            if(countArray[i] != 0) {
            if(page_seq[i] > maxPage) {
                    maxPage = page_seq[i];
                    maxPageIdx = i;
            }
    }
    for(i=0; i < seq_len; ++i) {
            if(countArray[0] < countArray[i])
                    countArray[0] = countArray[i];
             scanf("%d",countArray[i]);
            most_freq = countArray[0];
    }
    for (i =0; i< seq_len; i++) {
            if(countArray[i]  > most_freq){
                    most_freq = countArray[i];
                    count++;
            }
    }
    }
    pinned_page = page_seq[maxPage];
    printf("pinned page %d\n", pinned_page);
```

it works with simple (1,2,3,4) numbers,and i get my each page frequency count and i see highest counted number but with in ex.
       `139595776`
       `139538432`
       `139534336`
       `139632640`
these numbers it doesn't show me the highest counted number, instead im getting SEGMENTATION FAULT(core dumped)

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `scanf("%d",countArray[i]);` -->> `scanf("%d", &countArray[i]);` (the scanf makes little sense, though, maybe you intended printf() ? )

Comment: Maybe you go out of bounds of `countArray`? Have you tried using a debugger to catch the crash in action and locate where it happens in your code? Have you checked the values of all involved variables at that location? Do they look sane?

Comment: Typically arrays are stored in rows. So more horizontally. - _what do you mean with "vertically"??_ Said that: we are not a debugging site. Provide a [mcve] and learn [ask].

Comment: `pinned_page = page_seq[maxPage];` --> `pinned_page = page_seq[maxPageIdx];`

Answer (score 0):

You may have problems with big numbers, because you are using int. Basic signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−32,767, +32,767] range;[3][4] thus, it is at least 16 bits in size. Try to work with long instead of int, maybe that helps on your problem.